# iPhone app crashes on following scenario

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, notifications

iPhone app crashes in the following scenario.

**Steps:**

Install the app on iPhone device with a free developer account.

Turn on the LocalNotification click "Allow".
And then go to iPhone setting and click the date & Time and change the date one day ahead and kill the installed app from the background (via swipe up).

Reset the Date & Time on tap Set Automatically switch on.
Now when trying to open the installed app it's crashing.

If anyone facing the same issue please let me know how can I resolve it?

Since app kill from background debugs mode X-code with the app is removed.
I check on Analytic Data no crash report found.

**Using X-Code 9.4.1 iOS Version 11.4.1 on Device.**

Comment: You need a paid developer account.  By changing the date you are triggering the kill switch in iOS that kills free apps after a couple of days

Comment: @Paulw11 I completely agree about three days free app will not work in default.  If user change only one day and come back to original day, the app will not work.  I want to know is it default behaviour of app?

Comment: I suspect that Apple has a check to prevent people from manipulating the date to get around the restriction.  When the date goes backwards this is triggered and your app is no longer permitted to run.  This won't be a problem with an app built with a paid membership

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your comments it’s really help me.